# How to group tests using specs2?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, hierarchy, specs2

I'm used to JUnit, in JUnit it is possible to group several tests (usually related to a class) just by defining these tests in a single file (class) and annotating them with `@Test`. Then, to run several of these tests, a `TestSuite` is created with `@Suite.SuiteClasses` and so on.

In specs2 it is possible to group several tests at two different levels extending some `Specification`. For example:

```
  "Whatever" should {
    "do its job when possible" in {
      whatever(new Thing).work must beSome
    }
    "return none when not possible" in {
      whatever(null).work must beNone
    }
  }
```

We can group several `Specification` of this type in a single file, and each one of them can pack several checks, each check would be like a `@Test`, each group like a file in JUnit and then each `Specification` as a `Suite` in JUnit, except a `Suite` is splitted into several classes and a `Specification` is in a single class (i.e. file), which tends to produce huge files.

So the question is two fold:

- Where should I put the stuff as a matter of organization and readability: a `Specification` and the things that each class should do, i.e. the checks that it should pass.
- If the whole group of tests is split into several files, how can I create a `Suite` that groups them if possible in a hierarchical way, e.g. as [`Suites`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Suites) for ScalaTest.

BTW: I'm using Specs2 because I think it is the standard (was by default with the archetype, a (very reduced) small (and anecdotal) sample corroborates this [[1](https://github.com/spray/spray), [2](https://github.com/twitter/summingbird)]), but I am considering to use ScalaTest. Judging by numbers ([specs2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.specs2), [scalatest](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest)) that may be the best option to follow standards and customs of the Scala community. I mention this because an answer like "it's not possible, use ScalaTest" would be acceptable for these reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ***specs2*** there is no concept of a hierarchical suite. A Specification is just a list of examples. Even when you group them with `xxx should yyy`, this just affects the way the examples are displayed in the console, with more or less indentation.

On the other hand there are ways to organize specifications with ***specs2***:

- [references](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.2.0/org.specs2.guide.ReferenceOtherSpecifications.html)
- [tags](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.2.0/org.specs2.guide.Selection.html#use-tags)

#### References

You can create a hierarchy of specifications by creating a top-level specification referencing other ones:

```
// code for specs2 3.x
class ParentSpec extends Specification { def is = s2"""
  These are all the important specifications about our domain
  ${"child1" ~ ChildSpec1}   
  ${"child2" ~ ChildSpec2}   
  """
}
```

The child specifications can reference other specifications and so on. What's different from JUnit (and possibly from ScalaTest) is that your reference graph doesn't need to be a tree. When you execute a Specification with the [`all`](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.1/org.specs2.guide.ArgumentsReference.html#reporting) argument

```
sbt> test-only ParentSpec -- all
```

then dependencies are followed from the `ParentSpec` so that the low-level dependencies are executed before the high-level ones. And any cycles are broken so that you won't be executing things infinitely (or get a `StackOverflowError`).

#### Tags

Tags are a very convenient way to classify things because a given "thing" doesn't need to belong to only one category. This was, at the time, one of the great improvements brought by [TestNG](http://testng.org). In ***specs2*** you can tag single examples or whole specifications and then declare which examples you want to run based on the inclusion/exclusion of some tags. For example

```
class Spec1 extends mutable.Specification { section("functional")
   "simple test" >> ok

   tag("io")
   "a bit of IO" >> ok
}

class Spec2 extends mutable.Specification { section("functional")
   "another simple test" >> ok

   tag("io")
   "another bit of IO" >> ok
}
```

Then you can execute only the specifications with the `functional` tag but not with the examples having the `io` tag

```
sbt> test-only -- include functional exclude io
```

#### Organization

Using references and tags you can probably imagine several ways to slice and dice your test source:

- you can use references to create a main "taxonomy" of specifications
- you can use tags to create "cross-cutting" concerns like `io`, `slow`, `database`, `scalacheck`...

Note that you can also mix all of the above and have tags on your references, specifications with both examples and references, and so on.

The criteria for choosing a given structure are:

- the navigation around concepts in the code base
- the execution speed of different suites
- the necessity to re-run only some aspects of your tests after a change
- the infrastructure constraints (not everything can run in any environment)

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, thank you. I think there are two different (syntactic) "styles" to specify specs2 tests, so I will check the documentation for the other one as well. This definitively answers the questions. Thank you.