# Getting test-only to work outside SBT console

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

I'm using Specs2 for tests, with latest Play, Scala and SBT.

*In sbt console*, this works great, running only tests in UserServiceSpec:

```
[my-project] $ test-only services.UserServiceSpec
```

*Outside* sbt console, in project root directory, this does **not** work:

```
$ sbt test-only services.UserServiceSpec
```

This runs **all** the tests. (Same happens with [`testOnly`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#testOnly).)

How is `test-only` supposed to work outside sbt console?

**Follow-up question**: using [Specs2 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163830/56285), how to execute only tagged tests on the command line, outside sbt console?

```
$ sbt test-only -- include unit
```

The above, again, tries to to execute *all* tests (while `test-only -- include unit` in sbt console works fine).

Basically, I'd like to run all *unit tests* on a CI server, and Specs2 tags seem like a good tool for separating different kinds of tests. In this scenario I couldn't use the sbt console, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sbt consider two parameters as two separate commands. You should mark it as one.

Try: `sbt "testOnly services.UserServiceSpec"`

Comment: Ah, that was easy. Thanks!